# MongoDB and Java: concept-wise vision

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I'm working on a Java web service that allows users to interact (CRUD operations) with data stored in mongoDB. Concept-wise, there is one thing that bothers me:

Java is object oriented, and you define your object's attributes permanently when you define your class, and you are not supposed to modify them dynamically after class definition.

In the case of my web service, mongoDB is used because the structure and content of documents will probably change through time.

I have the impression mongoDB and Java are not similar in terms of flexibility. I have not found any sources discussing this issue.

I've thought about two different solutions:

**First solution**

My first idea was to create model classes that would look like this:

```
package classes;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;

import com.mongodb.DBObject;

@XmlRootElement
public class Plante extends Model{

    private ObjectId _id;
    private String name;

    public Plante(){}

    public Plante(String nom){
        this.name = nom;
    }

    public Plante(ObjectId id, String nom){
        this._id = id;
        this.name = nom;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String get_id(){
        return this._id.toString();
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String nom){
        this.name = nom;
    }

    public void set_id(ObjectId id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    public Document toDocument(){
        Document resultat = new Document();
        resultat.put("name", this.getName());
        return resultat;
    }
}
```

For retrieving data and inserting it I'd have functions of this type:

```
@Override
public <T extends Model> ArrayList<T> findAll() {
    ArrayList<T> resultats = new ArrayList<T>();
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        FindIterable<Document> allDocs = this.collection.find();
        for(Document doc : allDocs){
            T element;
            element = (T) gson.fromJson(doc.toJson(), Class.forName("classes." + nomClasse));
            resultats.add(element);
        } 
    }
    catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultats;
}

@Override
public String insert(Model newM){
    this.collection.insertOne(newM.toDocument());
    return "OK";
}
```

However, I have the impression this solution isn't really neat because if someone wants to add an Object that has a new type of attribute, my web service would just ignore this new attribute.

I'm using Jersey (JAX-RS) and here is my function that is called when I try to do a "post" call:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postElement(final Plante plante){
    return super.post(plante);
}
```

I'm sorry if my code isn't clear, the architecture is rather complex and isn't important to understand for this question.

**Second solution**

Since POJOs are not that flexible compared to mongoDB documents, I thought of another solution where I'd simply not have any "Object" class, but thanks to the URL called, I'd know in which collection the user wants to insert an object.
For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/webservice/plante
```

With a GET on this url I'd simply insert the JSON received in the body of the request directly in the collection "plante".

What is your opinion on these two solutions? Is the second one dirty? Or is it better than the first?
Is there another solution?

**PS**: I can't really change language now even if Java doesn't appear as a good choice since I'm at the end of my internship and this web service also does lots of other stuff.

**PS2**: I'm sorry if my question seems stupid, I'm a newcomer to the whole noSQL universe

Comment: Your second solution kinda looks like how you would interact with a REST API. Check this thread: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/difference-between-rest-and-crud and read more on the subject, it might be what you want.

Comment: My web service is a REST API. I'm just searching for the most elegant solution for all the operations I have in my web service concerning interactions with my mongoDB database.